# Why the name of the form variable is being displayed? django

Tags: python, django

I have this form

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

LETTERS= [
    ('a', 'a)'),
    ('b', 'b)'),
    ('c', 'c)'),
    ('d', 'd)'),
    ('e', 'e)'),

    ]
class CHOICES(forms.Form):
    NUMS = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=LETTERS)
```

and this view
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from questoes.models import Questao
from .forms import CHOICES

# Create your views here.
def prova(request):
    questoes = Questao.objects.order_by('?')[:5]
    form = CHOICES
    if request.method=='POST':
        dados = {
            'questoes': questoes, 
            'form':form(request.POST)
        }
        return render(request,'provas/prova.html', dados)
    else:
        dados = {
            'questoes': questoes, 
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request,'provas/prova.html', dados)
```

I can't figure out why the name NUMS (the form's variable name) is being rendered in the HTML. :(

[image]

Comment: It's label for your form field

Comment: You can a) use `ChoiceField(..., label='')` to or b) render form manually in template to get rid of this label.

Comment: Hi @Felipe, as you continue with Python and share code or get help from places like this site, it would be good to get your code following some [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) or specifically for [Django applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/). It makes assisting easier as certain assumptions can be made about something all in uppercase for example.

Comment: @AMG, thanks for the advice. As I'm not a professional developer I didn't know those conventions. I'll try to follow!

Comment: @SUTerliakov, that solved my problem! thanks a lot!